# C# input vector3 for calculating barycentric coordinates

Tags: c#, input, vector-graphics

I'm learning in school something little about barycentric coordinates, I have found code below which calculates if the point is in the triangle. But I can't figure out how to change the code so I can enter values for points from standard input. What should I do?

```
public static bool PointInTriangle(ref Vector3 A, ref Vector3 B, ref Vector3 C, ref Vector3 P)
{
    // Prepare our barycentric variables
    Vector3 u = B - A;
    Vector3 v = C - A;
    Vector3 w = P - A;

    Vector3 vCrossW = Vector3.Cross(v, w);
    Vector3 vCrossU = Vector3.Cross(v, u);
    // Test sign of r
    if (Vector3.Dot(vCrossW, vCrossU) < 0)
         return false;

    Vector3 uCrossW = Vector3.Cross(u, w);
    Vector3 uCrossV = Vector3.Cross(u, v);

    // Test sign of t
    if (Vector3.Dot(uCrossW, uCrossV) < 0)
        return false;

    // At this piont, we know that r and t and both > 0
    float denom = uCrossV.Length;
    float r = vCrossW.Length / denom;
    float t = uCrossW.Length / denom;

    return (r <= 1 && t <= 1 && r + t <= 1);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "From standard input"?

Comment: Do you mean "you do not want to use parameters with `ref`?

Comment: Im not sure. I want to run the program, and then program should write: enter coordinates for A,B,c, and then user write it in. after that it asks: enter coordinates for P. and that is forwarded to this function

Comment: Oh, what you're asking is the whole program structure. I'll edit my answer with a link to an helpful page for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at [this Walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78(v=vs.90).aspx) of how to create a simple application. After, you can look at [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457(v=vs.71).aspx) that explains how to prompt for parameters. Once this is done, you can call your function using :

```
bool isInTrigangle = MyClass.PointInTriangle(a, b, c, p);
```

I wrote `MyClass` because I do not know the name of the class that has this static method. I also didn't put the parameters as `ref` because I supposed you changed the signature of the function to :

```
public static bool PointInTriangle(Vector3 A, Vector3 B, Vector3 C, Vector3 P)
```